# css style on a element doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap right now and I have problem with changing properties of an a element in css file.

When I change e.g. color using inline method Link than it works fine, but when I try to change color in my external css file it doesn't work. e.g. 
    a {
    color: red; 
    }

I even gave a class to each a element but it still doesn't work.

Here is my html and css:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container" id="cont1">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="nav-a">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="nav-a">Over ons</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> 
            <a id="vacatures" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-a" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Vacatures <span class="caret"></span> </a> 
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="vacatures"> 
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li> 
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> 
            <a id="nieuws" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-a" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Nieuws <span class="caret"></span> </a> 
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="nieuws"> 
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li> 
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> 
            <a id="werkgevers" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-a" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">         Werkgevers <span class="caret"></span> </a> 
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="werkgevers"> 
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li> 
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="nav-a">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

And than I tried to access to this a element inside nav:

```
a { 
  color: red;
{
or
.nav-a {color: red;} or li.nav-a , li a etc.
```

Can someone please explain why I have a trouble with this a element ?

CSS file:

```
body, html {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

nav {
width: 100vw;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
background-color: white;
height: 120px;  
}


nav li {
font-size: 18px;
padding-top: 41px;
}

li.nav-a {
color: red;
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to link to your stylesheet?

Comment: Stupid question, but have you cleared the browser cache?

Comment: Yeah, I did all of that, but still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be here:

```css
li.nav-a {
  color: red;
}
```

It should be:

```css
li.nav a {
  color: red;
}
```

Remove the "-" sign to access `<a>` tag.

Edit: Or maybe you mean these:

```css
li .nav-a {
  color: red;
}
```

Since `nav-a` is a class name (I didn't notice it earlier), then its parent is `<li>`, then these might solve your problem. Just separate the `li` and `.nav-a`.

Comment: I already tried all of that, but it still doesn't work.
I commented out everything in my css file except that a tag but it still doesn't work. css file is included in html file after bootstrap.min.css file.

Comment: After you update your css file, clear cache. It is a common problem. Your old css file is being stored as a cache that's why it didn't display yet, so clear cache and done.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it happens because propably you include your bootstrap after your CSS stylesheet. In this situation bootstrap CSS override your external stylesheet.
You can try change include order.

The second try may be to add `!important` directive for example

```
li.nav-a{
color: red!important;
}
```

But your selector is bad
You can do this using for example like this

```
.navbar-nav a{
    color: red;
}
```

If you want all links to be color red

Comment: I tried it before, but it doesn't work. It looks like that a tag is completely ignored. I have no clue what's going on here.

Comment: Impossible. You did something wrong.
You can check in developers console (f12) if the style is override or if it appears (if it's not than you have bad selector)
try to use the second one with !important

Comment: I checked in console on chrome how is that a element referenced and I wrote it like this: .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a and now it works. I had the same problem only with an a element, few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't answer your question directly, for future reference, download and install FireBug for Firefox and use it to inspect element...  The list of CSS styles and how they were applied to that element ought to appear on the RHS.

Comment: I have already installed firebug on firefox, but I don't use it so oft. I check and there is only default settings for a tag, I guess, nothing else.

Comment: Which in itself would show that your css style isn't being applied.  The question then is why... wtf??!!  but at least it would rule it out.  Sometimes rules of precedence can play a part too but at least it's sorted. :D